# How to stop all instances of cron?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I have a cron job that executes a rake task in rails. I noticed in the log that it was running the task 4 times everytime it was executed. The problem is that there are 4 instances of cron running.

I ran:

```
/etc/init.d/crond stop
```

And now there are only three.

Running:

```
ps -ef | grep cron
```

I see this:

```
root      1029     1  0 Oct20 ?        00:00:01 crond
root      6980  6094  0 21:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep cron
root     15170     1  0 Oct26 ?        00:00:00 crond start
root     15186     1  0 Oct26 ?        00:00:00 crond stop
```

So my question is how do I stop the other instances. When I run the stop command now I get this:

Stopping crond: cannot stop crond: crond is not running.   [FAILED]

Any ideas? Do the other instances have different names? Is there a way to kill all instances as once?

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for unix.stackexchange.com, it may get closed as off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo killall crond
```

Comment: With `killall`, it's worth noting that on *some* Unix systems (Solaris comes to mind), `killall` kills *all* processes. This usually causes your computer to stop entirely.

Comment: ...that'd still fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are going to have to kill them manually

`killall crond`

or

`kill -9 pid1 pid2 ...`

Then restart with init.d

Comment: With `killall`, it's worth noting that on *some* Unix systems (Solaris comes to mind), `killall` kills *all* processes. This usually causes your computer to stop entirely.

Comment: He used a linux tag, so it's probably not Solaris. On linux this send-sigterm-to-all-pids tool was renamed to `killall5`.

Comment: Only use `-9` as a last resort. Use the default which is `SIGTERM` (15). This gives processes a chance to do cleanup and exit gracefully.